# Handle signal with sigaction

Tags: c, unix, signals

I need to handle some signal with sigaction, but when I compile my code I get this error:

> warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

the code is:

```
struct sigaction hup_act;
...
hup_act.sa_flags=SA_SIGINFO;
hup_act.sa_sigaction = sighupHandler;
sigaction(SIGHUP, &hup_act, NULL);
```

Warning is on hup_act.sa_sigaction assignment. This warning causes a segmentation fault when I send sighup to my application.

Comment: Please show declaration of your sighupHandler function. It is probably wrong type.

Comment: void sighupHandler(siginfo_t *info)

Comment: `void sighupHandler(int, siginfo_t *, void *);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `SA_SIGINFO`is set in `struct sigaction`'s member `sa_flags` use a method of type

```
void signalhandler(int, siginfo_t *, void *);
```

as handler function to be assigned to `struct sigaction`'s member `sa_sigaction`

else use a method of type

```
void signalhandler(int);
```

as handler function to be assigned to `struct sigaction`'s member `sa_handler`.

Answer (score 5):

Your sighupHandler must be one of the two below:

```
void sighupHandler(int) //for sa_handler
```

or

```
void sighupHandler(int, signinfo_t *, void *) //for sa_sigaction which is your case
```

For more info on this refer [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) and [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/signal.h.html)

EDIT: Please refer to below and my above suggested links for better clarity. I think in your case because of common storage as suggested below, compiler is only generating a warning, else it would have generated an error.

> The sigaction structure is defined as something like:

```
struct sigaction {
    void     (*sa_handler)(int);
    void     (*sa_sigaction)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);
    sigset_t   sa_mask;
    int        sa_flags;
    void     (*sa_restorer)(void);
};
```

> On some architectures a union is involved: do not assign to both `sa_handler` and `sa_sigaction`.

Comment: `.sa_restorer` is obsolete and non-POSIX. It's better not to include it in examples.